# Which third part control alow on enter key move next cell in DataGrid control - visual studio

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, datagrid, devexpress, telerik-grid

Is it possible to set option on DG control something like moveNextOnEnter Key through cell? I know that is not possible on standard dg control, but is it possible using third part controls??

Comment: Why have you decided that required behavior is not possible with standard WPF DataGrid? What have you tried?

Comment: Im new to vb.net and i have try some basic staff but ! I have looking on net and and I could not find anything. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it by DevExpress.

```
<dxg:GridControl>
<dxg:GridControl.View>
<dxg:TableView EnterMoveNextColumn="True"/>
</dxg:GridControl.View>
</dxg:GridControl>
```